# D3js, how set points based on axis values (not pixels)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have this kind of plot . In that I placed points by pixels.

```js
let svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([20 , 20000]).range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([-18 , 18]).range([height, 0]),
    axisBottom = d3.axisBottom(x),
    axisLeft =  d3.axisLeft(x),
    points =[[100, 100], [300, 200]],
    circleRadius = 10;
    
    // How can I set points if I have data like
  // points =[[5, 6000], [-10, 18500]], not pixels but axis units


svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis axis--x')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height/2 + ')')
    .call(axisBottom);
    
svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'axis axis--y')
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

let groupForCircles = svg.append('g').attr('id', 'groupForCircles')

points.forEach(e => {
    groupForCircles.append("g")
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", e[0])
        .attr("cy", height/2)
        .attr("r", circleRadius)
        .style("fill", "purple")
})
```

```css
svg {
          border: 1px solid #ccc;
          display: block;
          margin: auto;
          overflow: visible;
          margin-top: 25px;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="300"></svg>
```

And the question is how I can set points on plot if I only have values based on axis?
For example I have `[5, 6000]` where first number is Y axis value and second number is X axis value. How can I put point on graphic based on that values instead of pixels? Thank you!

And here is [jsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/14x5rktb/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The x and y scales are used to convert your values to the appropriate chart coordinates. To add your coordinates, you just need to use the scales that you have created to generate the correct x and y coordinates:

```
groupForCircles
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx', d => x(d[0]) ) // `x` is your x scale, `y` is the y scale
  .attr('cy', d => y(d[1]) )
```

It looks like you have got the x and y values switched around in your suggested data points, so I have altered the code slightly to account for that. I've also used standard d3 data binding to facilitate addition and manipulation of the points, rather than a `forEach` loop:

```
const moreData = [ [5, 6000], [-10, 18500], [2, 2000], [-18, 100] ]

groupForCircles.selectAll('.dataPoint')
  .data(moreData)             // bind the data
 .enter()                     // this is the new data being added to the chart
 .append('circle')            // add a circle element for each data element
  .classed('dataPoint', true)
  .attr('cx', d => x(d[1]) )  // use the second of the pair as the x coordinate
  .attr('cy', d => y(d[0]) )  // and the first as the y
  .attr('r', 4)
  .style('fill', 'deepskyblue');
```

Full demo:

```js
let svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([20 , 20000]).range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([-18 , 18]).range([height, 0]),
    axisBottom = d3.axisBottom(x),
    axisLeft =  d3.axisLeft(x),
    points =[[100, 100], [300, 200]],
    moreData = [ [5, 6000], [-10, 18500], [2, 2000], [-18, 100] ],
    circleRadius = 10;
    
    // How can I set points if I have data like
  // points =[[5, 6000], [-10, 18500]], not pixels but axis units


svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis axis--x')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height/2 + ')')
    .call(axisBottom);
    
svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'axis axis--y')
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

let groupForCircles = svg.append('g').attr('id', 'groupForCircles')

points.forEach(e => {
    groupForCircles.append("g")
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", e[0])
        .attr("cy", height/2)
        .attr("r", circleRadius)
        .style("fill", "purple")
})

groupForCircles.selectAll('.dataPoint')
  .data(moreData)
  .enter()
 .append('circle')
  .classed('dataPoint', true)
  .attr('cx', d => x(d[1]) )
  .attr('cy', d => y(d[0]) )
  .attr('r', 4)
  .style('fill', 'deepskyblue');
```

```css
svg {
          border: 1px solid #ccc;
          display: block;
          margin: auto;
          overflow: visible;
          margin-top: 25px;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="300"></svg>
```